# How to manipulate (split and concatenate) String field in MongoDB?

Tags: json

I have a MongoDB collection with some documents that have a field called user_profile_image. The value of this field is a URL.

I want to write a mongo update statement that will change the base of the URL but keep the name.

For example:
`https://enggprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/engagement/MALE.jpg`
would change to
`https://kpitblob.kpit.com/engagement/MALE.jpg`.

I want to find all documents containing this field and apply the above mutation.

The sample document:

```
[

  {

    "_id": 123,

    "ticket_number": 143,

    "ticket_string": "143",

    "from_system": "VMS",

    "ticket_name": "Visitor Management System - Vendor/ Visitor Request",

    "category_id": 41,

    "ticket_status": "Approved",

    "status_id": 60,

    "status_color": "#a84545",

    "created_by_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "GUESTORVISITOR",

      "user_name": "Prompt Personnel",

      "user_profile_image": "https://enggprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/engagement/MALE.jpg"

    },

    "created_for": "GUESTORVISITOR",

    "created_for_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "GUESTORVISITOR",

      "user_name": "Prompt Personnel",

      "user_profile_image": "https://enggprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/engagement/MALE.jpg"

    },

    "json_data": {

      "data": [

        {

          "label_name": "Meeting From",

          "field_value": "8th Jan 2019 15:42 "

        },

        {

          "label_name": "Meeting To",

          "field_value": "8th Jan 2019 18:30"

        },

        {

          "label_name": "Participants",

          "field_value": "Prompt  Personnel ( Tata Team) "

        }

      ]

    },

    "current_approver_level": 10,

    "created_date": "8th Jan 2019 15:42",

    "original_created_date": "2019-01-08 15:42:00",

    "priority": 5,

    "assigned_to": "",

    "assigned_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "",

      "user_name": "",

      "user_profile_image": ""

    },

    "assigned_on": "",

    "pending_approval_with": "",

    "pending_with_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "",

      "user_name": "",

      "user_profile_image": ""

    },

    "project_id": "null",

    "project_name": "null",

    "org_id": "",

    "location_id": 0,

    "upload_allowed": false,

    "updated_on": "2020-03-05 17:35:00",

    "is_internal": true,

    "process_id": 473,

    "admin": ", KESHAVP",

    "roaadmin": "",

    "delegated_to": "",

    "external_url": "#",

    "admin_email": "KESHAV.PATNE@KPIT.COM"

  },

  {

    "_id": 456,

    "ticket_number": 144,

    "ticket_string": "144",

    "from_system": "VMS",

    "ticket_name": "Visitor Management System - Vendor/ Visitor Request",

    "category_id": 41,

    "ticket_status": "Approved",

    "status_id": 60,

    "status_color": "#a84545",

    "created_by_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "GUESTORVISITOR",

      "user_name": "Chaitanya Bhavthankar",

     "user_profile_image": "https://enggprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/engagement/MALE.jpg"

    },

    "created_for": "GUESTORVISITOR",

    "created_for_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "GUESTORVISITOR",

      "user_name": "Chaitanya Bhavthankar",

      "user_profile_image": "https://enggprodblob.blob.core.windows.net/engagement/MALE.jpg"

    },

    "json_data": {

      "data": [

        {

          "label_name": "Meeting From",

          "field_value": "8th Jan 2019 15:53 "

        },

        {

          "label_name": "Meeting To",

          "field_value": "8th Jan 2019 18:30"

        },

        {

          "label_name": "Participants",

          "field_value": "Chaitanya  Bhavthankar (Self) "

        }

      ]

    },

    "current_approver_level": 10,

    "created_date": "8th Jan 2019 15:53",

    "original_created_date": "2019-01-08 15:53:00",

    "priority": 5,

    "assigned_to": "",

    "assigned_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "",

      "user_name": "",

      "user_profile_image": ""

    },

    "assigned_on": "",

    "pending_approval_with": "",

    "pending_with_info": {

      "user_emailId": "",

      "user_id": "",

      "user_name": "",

      "user_profile_image": ""

    },

    "project_id": "null",

    "project_name": "null",

    "org_id": "",

    "location_id": 0,

    "upload_allowed": false,

    "updated_on": "2020-03-05 17:35:00",

    "is_internal": true,

   "process_id": 473,

    "admin": "",

    "roaadmin": "",

    "delegated_to": "",

    "external_url": "#"

  }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your the above links are the same for all, then you can try the following aggregation. Learn more about [substring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) and [concatenation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/).

```
db.<your_collection>.aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: { new_url: { $concat: [ "https://kpitblob.kpit.com", {$substr: ["user_profile_image",43]}]}}
    }
]);
```

Or if the links are dynamic, then you can try the following one. Like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682122/how-to-update-string-field-in-mongodb-and-manipulate-string-values)

```
let newBase = 'https://kpitblob.kpit.com';
db.<your_collection>.find({user_profile_image:url}).forEach(data => {
  let urlObj = new URL(URL);
  let newUrl = newbase + urlObj.pathname;
  // Then you can save the new url in the DB.
});
```

You can learn more about the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) object on MDN.